# what is the name of this gdb extension?

Tags: c, gdb

please see attached image, where the stack and data area are nicely shown in the gdb as text:

[image: showing unknown gdb extension]

originally found in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAr2cjLPufA&t=1390s at 24:30

the audio is not good so I didn't get the name for the extension.

does somebody know and would be so kind to indicate a source?

much appreciated.

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mammon . The guess is https://github.com/mammon/gdbinit , see the comments below the video.